# Quartz is drawing on a different window

Tags: macos, nsview, nswindow, quartz-2d

I am trying to draw some pixels (NSRects that are 1x1) on a NSWindow in mac os, but when I do that it randomly pics a window to draw it on (see below). It is supposed to be on the left window.

[image: strange]

---

```
-(void)draw:(NSRect)rect {
NSGraphicsContext *ctx = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

double perlinValue = [[[xValues objectAtIndex:x] objectAtIndex:y] floatValue];
[[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:perlinValue green:perlinValue blue:perlinValue alpha:1.0f] set];
NSRectFill(CGRectMake(x, y, 1, 1));

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

Comment: check your NSView. It should be on other window where u are getting drawing.